# How Remove backslash from JSON Result -DataSet

Tags: json

I want to remove backslash from json result

current result like this:
    "{\"Info\":[{\"Full_Eng_Nmae\":\"anda norse\",\"email\":\"keer0@gm

my code is like this

```
  public string GetDetails(string OrderID)
        {

            OrderContract order = new OrderContract();
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            try
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);
                con.Close();
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select  Full_Eng_Nmae,email,mobile,client_id from Students where Center_id='" + OrderID + "'", con);


                da.Fill(dataSet,"Info");

                dataSet.AcceptChanges();
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataSet);
                return json;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new FaultException<string>
                        (ex.Message);

            }


        }
```

any one can help me plz?
Thanks

also this full of my code

my Interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IOrderService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetOrderDetails/{OrderID}",
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string GetOrderDetails(string OrderID);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet there is no backslash, but the printing code that you are using is adding them.

Comment: but i need like this format for JSON in xcode (ios)